# Configuring several endpoints for a single service

Tags: java, spring-boot, soap, wsdl, cxf

I'm using `cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxws` to write a simple SOAP service. The WSDL has one service and several ports, that look like this

```
<wsdl:port name="myServiceSoap11Endpoint" binding="ns:myServiceSoap11Binding">
    <soap:address location="http://example.com/services/myService.myServiceSoap11Endpoint/"/>
</wsdl:port>
<wsdl:port name="myServiceSoap12Endpoint" binding="ns:myServiceSoap12Binding">
    <soap12:address location="http://example.com/services/myService.myServiceSoap12Endpoint/"/>
</wsdl:port>
```

Both bindings are pretty much identical and point to the same PortType.

In my java code I configure the endpoints using the spring boot `@Configuration` mechanism. I create a separate endpoint for every port.

```
// The class MyService was auto-generated by wsdl2java
@Bean
public Endpoint endpointMyServiceSoap11() {
    EndpointImpl endpoint = new EndpointImpl(springBus, new MyServiceImplementor());
    endpoint.setWsdlLocation(MyService.WSDL_LOCATION.toString());
    endpoint.setServiceName(MyService.SERVICE);
    endpoint.setEndpointName(MyService.MyServiceSoap11Endpoint);

    endpoint.publish("/myService.myServiceSoap11Endpoint");

    return endpoint;
}

@Bean
public Endpoint endpointMyServiceSoap12() {
    EndpointImpl endpoint = new EndpointImpl(springBus, new MyServiceImplementor());
    endpoint.setWsdlLocation(MyService.WSDL_LOCATION.toString());
    endpoint.setServiceName(MyService.SERVICE);
    endpoint.setEndpointName(MyService.MyServiceSoap12Endpoint);

    endpoint.publish("/myService.myServiceSoap12Endpoint");

    return endpoint;
}
```

This is somewhat working, but the problem starts when I want to get a WSDL file. Both endpoints are published as a separate services, and they both provide their own version of WSDL, with only one port being correct in each.

Is there a way to publish both endpoints as parts of a common service, so that `/myService?WSDL` returned a correct WSDL with both endpoints?

Answer (score 0):

After some meddling I found out that it is impossible to do what I want. Still, there is one way of at least getting the correct WSDL file. You can do it by using the autoRewriteSoapAddressForAllServices property, e.g. like this

```
endpoint.setProperties(Map.of(WSDLGetUtils.AUTO_REWRITE_ADDRESS_ALL, true))
```

This property won't work with `cxf.path` however, you need to put everything into `server.servlet.contextPath`, as the resulting paths in WSDL are created basically by combining contextPath with endpoint publishing path.